# How to set OrderList width in PrimeFaces

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

How can I change the widht of a ListOrder in Primefaces?

I tried with width or style but it does not do want i want. It stays small with a scroll:

[image: a busy cat]

Do you have any idea?

i tried with css:

```
    .orderlist {
        width:1000px;
    }
```

and 
        p:orderList styleClass="orderlist" ...

Doing so, my page is larger but the area containing the data (and the scrollable list remains very small.

Comment: *I tried with width or style but it does not do want i want* then what do you want? You must use primefaces particular CSS for this.

Comment: You mean styleClass and css? I tried that too.

Comment: Then please post what have you tried and why you say *it does not do want I want*.

Comment: Hello @user1667910 : I think you are facing this problem due to fixed width of `.ui-widget-content` styleClass. You can try this `.ui-widget-content{width: 5000000px;}`.

Comment: Hello Diganta, thank you for your help. If i do that, other components are larger but not this one.

Comment: Hello @user1667910 : In this situation check your layout of firebug for which component the width is not increasing.

Comment: This is what i get from firebug: <td>
<ul class="ui-widget-content ui-orderlist-list ui-corner-all ui-sortable"></ul>
<select id="tabViewSections:pictures:pictureList234_values" class="ui-helper-hidden" multiple="true" name="tabViewSections:pictures:pictureList234_values"></select>
</td> is the problem in <td>? Can't we change it's width?

Answer (score 2):

Coloque este código em style.css

```
.ui-orderlist .ui-orderlist-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:auto;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
}

.ui-orderlist .ui-orderlist-list li {
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 2px;
}

.ui-orderlist .ui-orderlist-button {
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:0.3em;
}

.ui-orderlist .ui-orderlist-button.ui-button-text-icon-primary {
    width:100%;
}

.ui-orderlist .ui-orderlist-item {
    cursor:pointer;
    border:0px none;
    font-weight: inherit;
}

.ui-orderlist .ui-orderlist-caption {
    text-align: center;
    padding:4px 10px 4px 10px;
    border-bottom:0px none;
}

.ui-orderlist table {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Comment: While that code may answer the question, providing at least a little explanation will help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

The following CSS works fine for me:

```
.ui-orderlist-list {
    width:300px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it takes more place, but the list with columns stays small with a scrollbar. Isn't it the same for you=?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What do you mean the column stays small with a scrollbar? If you want to see how it looks for me, try going to [this site](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/orderList.jsf) and going into the console and typing `$('.ui-orderlist-list').css('width', '100px')`

Comment: The primefaces example is exactly like mine is. But i have much more data/columns to display. Thus, it is too small. I was using a dataTable until now but i would like to be able to reorder the items using drag and drop.

Comment: On the `<p:column>`, try setting the width to 100%. So `<p:column style="width:100%">`

Comment: I'm still not clear on what exactly your problem is. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: i added the screenshot.

Comment: which version of primefaces and AS do you use?

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the long time in responding. It appears that you have a div within another div that is wrapping around the content. Try using FireBug or Chrome developer console to pull apart the HTML and find which element is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Put this code in style.css

```
.ui-orderlist-list-container {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```